# which Hadoop component can handle all the oracle queries.?

Tags: oracle, hadoop, shark-sql, presto

Which hadoop component can handle all the oracle functions & which has low latency..
Am thinking to use the components like Presto, Drill and Shark..
Can anyone tell which of the above technology can handle all the functions in oracle with low latency..
or atleast which has more compatibility & which can handle all the functions of oracle.. 
I have the flexibility to use more than one technology but am confused to use which one for which like functions compatible for which technology & which technology can give low latency..?

Answer (score 2):

Presto is designed to implement ANSI SQL and to execute queries with low latency (under 100ms for connectors that support it). Queries against Hive can execute in ~1s, depending on the speed of the Hive metastore (zero time if cached due to repeated access) and HDFS latency.

Regarding Oracle functionality, nothing in open source comes close. Oracle is a huge product with a ton of functionality. However, no one uses all of the functionality. Most people use a small subset. You will need to evaluate the different alternatives and decide which has the functionality subset that best meets your needs.

Disclosure: I am one of the creators of Presto.